# how to get images from XML file

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone. I need to get images from a local XML file and local folder that contain images. I am able to get a string from the XML file. But I don't how to get images through XML file. Please post some code or a link. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the path of your images (in local folder) in the xml as string. You can retrieve the path from xml and show the image from the file using:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePathRetrievedFromXML];
```

where 'filePathRetrievedFromXML' is your image's path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to be uploaded to serer then you have to convert the image to data and then pass it on as string in your xml file and on server side again convert the data to image and you will get the images stored locally to the webserver..

Another thing is if you want the local images in xml file and are going to use it locally then store the name of the images in the xml and fetch the name accordingly...